# How to disable all keyboard shortcuts for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

**I know how to modify them**, but there is no option to delete them, I can only replace them with another key combination, but I dont want to put some magical key combination to all possible functions, so when I accidentally press that combination, my computer explodes.

How do I disable all these keyboard shortcuts? I am willing to do hex-editing to destroy the program from bottom level to just get rid of this feature, but I dont know which offset to edit, so, if anyone has figured those out, please tell me.

Firefox version: 12.0

OS: Windows XP SP3

Comment: No answer was forthcoming here: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/725050  -- good luck!

Comment: Yep. I decided to change all my shortcuts to `CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+ADD` combination, which i hopefully never will press.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-in called keyconfig that lets you disable them.

Comment: that didnt do much, not sure if its because of the other plugin (Customizable Shortcuts). i think if you leave the shortcut empty, then it will use the default? which Customizable Shortcuts probably overrided then.

Comment: Thank you! After installing `Keybinder` pluging, ctrl+q no longer closes all my 20 tabs. Furthermore, console-style copying no longer evokes the heavy "view source" window.